# How to integrate $e^{x^2}$?

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I am stuck in this problem of integrating $e^{x^2}$. I was solving the linear differential equation of second order for damped oscillations in which i got this to solve

Comment: $e^{x^2}$ or $({e^x})^2$?

Comment: If you are integrating over the reals, it becomes $-i\sqrt{\pi}$

Answer (score 5):

The integral of the function $f(x)= e^{x^2}$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

The integral can be given in terms of the imaginary error function, $\text{erfi}(x)$, which is defined as:
$$\text{erfi}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x} e^{t^2} dt $$